# How to show postgres date on a html page using node server?

Tags: javascript

```
fetch('/clientes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const clientesTable = document.getElementById('clientes');
        // Adicionar linhas da tabela com os dados retornados
        data.forEach(cliente => {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            const codigoCell = document.createElement('td');
            const nomeCell = document.createElement('td');
            codigoCell.textContent = cliente.codigo;
            nomeCell.textContent = cliente.nome;
            row.appendChild(codigoCell);
            row.appendChild(nomeCell);
            clientesTable.appendChild(row);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

when i call my /clientes i have this result:

[{"codigo":1,"nome":"nome1111"},{"codigo":2,"nome":"nome22"}]

i wanna format this information on html page

how im put this information o html table?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> app.get('/clientes', (req, res) => {
>     pool.query('SELECT codigo,nome FROM cliente', (error, results) => {
>         if (error) {
>             throw error;
>         }
>         
>         res.send(results.rows);
>         res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/clientes.html"));
>         
>     });
> });
>
> const path = require('path');
> ```

my /clientes route

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).